# OP doesn't seem to get why it's not a good SO question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Please see the comments on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18018320/352765

The question is asking for opinions about whether IE is a good browser or not. He's basically trying to drum up a discussion.

My reading of the SO rules is that questions like that are not a good fit for the SO format, and should be closed.

The OP is arguing with that, and with several re-open votes, it looks like others agree with him.

I've tried to make my point in the comments, and the OP has argued his corner. In my opinion, the argument has got a little out of hand (this may be partly my fault for rising to the bait, so I apologise for that). It's not rude or crude or anything like that, but I think it might be time for a moderator to step in an make a final call -- should the question be closed or not?

Comment: If you feel the question is not useful, downvote. If you feel that it does not belong on the site, vote to close. Comments are a way to ask for clarification or improvement, but ensuring that the OP understands the action is nice but not strictly required. If the comment doesn't work to serve that purpose, no big deal. The OP can read the documentation that is presented after the close occurs.

Comment: Not answering question that you feel is so bad you have to take it to meta after voting to close it might be a good idea?

Comment: @Wooble - mea culpa. I dived in to answer before I thought about the quality. The point of me posting here on meta is that I feel I've done enough damage, so I'm taking my hands off and passing it to the mods.

Comment: The meta effect is probably going to get the referenced question downovted to oblivion, but will still probably secure the reopen votes needed, and of course there'll be 5 more to close and a mod is going to have to lock it to prevent a open/close war.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Can it be preemptively locked?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I think the mods have the ability to lock it whenever they want, but they will rarely exercise that ability unless it is clear the community can't do it themselves.  So my guess is they will leave it go unless it is reopened and closed and maybe reopned a 2nd time..

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul The first one is a duplicate. The second and third show zero research effort. They're all crappy questions, though I wouldn't close any but the first. How do any of those questions relate to the question under discussion (which is off topic)?

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul SO has a very specific focus.  Answerable questions with answers based solely on facts.  The 3 questions you linked, while bad, are actually better fits within the scope of the site because they actual questions and not invitation to discussions.  The referenced question here is nothing more than a discussion.  It is actually a pretty interesting discussion, but in no way fits the scope of SO.

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul There is no gatekeeper of SO that "allows" or "rejects" questions. Once a question has been asked community members that see it will take action to close it if it isn't suitable for the site. The mere existence of some poor questions that aren't closed isn't justification for giving free rein to discuss anything and everything.

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul: Yeah.  And your point is what?  BTW, the community is biased against all three questions you cited.  But not as much as against "hey, I've got an opinion, let's debate it!" type questions now.

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul: The SE sites have specific guidelines, and enforcing them is not BIASED. Expecting people to follow the rules here is how we keep these sites a useful resource. **Every question** I see that doesn't meet the guidelines gets a close vote; there's no bias. The help and about pages for all of the sites describe the questions that are on topic for that site. If you don't agree with the guidelines, post here on Meta to have them changed. If we disagree, and you don't like that result, you might want to look elsewhere for help on a site that meets your expectations. :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The OP said:

> This is a general discussion I would like to take up.

This is addressed in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

The OP also said:

> I know this is not a programming related question and maybe a better question for other SO sites, however my argument is since Stack Overflow is the widest used site it is better suited here.

The OP admits that the question isn't a good fit, and the OP is right. Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions.

Finally, the question is a vehicle to state an opinion and to generate opinionated responses:

> ...why are we still using IE when we have better choices like Chrome, Firefox, Safari?
>
> Personally I believe that a websites forte should be its functionality.
>
> This is an open ended question to enable a discussion on "Why we shouldn't ignore Internet Explorer?"

Again from the Help Center:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

For these reasons, the question is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: It almost sounds like the OP just quoted the FAQ when asking this. What a silly amount of research and effort put into something so totally wrong.

Answer (score 15):

The bottom line here is that no matter how many facts, references, and statistics you throw out here, the final answer to the question is still entirely based on opinion.

Some people believe that *all* browsers should be supported, some believe only the latest few should be supported, and some people believe only the ones they care about should be supported. Facts may help persuade them to change their view, but some stubborn people will never change their minds no matter how many facts you throw at them.

Comment: I would say this is the only good answer i finally got to why my question should be closed

Comment: So what do you suggest i do? Do i take my question off. I dont want to offend anybody on SO. Maybe the Mod's can have a look at it and pass q judgement on whether it can be edited to re-fit the rules of SO

Comment: You can't @AnaMaria. It has upvoted answers. And I personally see no way to edit it to make it appropriate. You want a discussion. That's not a good fit.

Comment: Can we at least clean the comments up on the original question? This meta post has enough.